# How can I optimize/refactor the sql like " order by column1 + column2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named *Topics* which has about a million records,
when I execute the SQL below:

```
 select * from Topics  order by ReplyCount+OfficialReplyCount desc  LIMIT 0,4;
```

It use more then 10 seconds to be finished. I have created indexes on columns ReplyCount and OfficialReplyCount separately, but there useless.
How can I improve the performance?

Comment: Have you run EXPLAIN to see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order By on computed column slows down query.
Create a new column having values `ReplyCount+OfficialReplyCount` and create index on it and then use this column name in Order By.

Comment: Also limit columns (avoid `select *`) if you do not really need all columns. If you did not already, try keeping code in a stored procedure if it permits you to do so. In my view, 10 seconds for a million records is not a big thing.

Comment: create new column is a good idea, but if don't change the application code, can i create a new column and index and use things like `order by ReplyCount+OfficialReplyCount` in the same time? And I think the trigger must be used to make the new_sum_column updated.